# SQL join while retaining the data

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm using an SQL join to show all my clients addresses using address_id and to check if the booking is completed(done 1=completed). The second join connects the user_id of addresses to clients (since 1 client can have more than 1 address).

Using php, if done=1 a button needs to appear but if there are any bookings under that address_id (i.e done=0) then no button apears.

```
    select *, coalesce(b.done, 1) completed
    from addresses c
    left join bookings b on b.address_id = c.address_id and b.done = 0  
    LEFT JOIN clients d ON c.client_id=d.client_id;
```

I have tried all the join methods. The button is appearing correctly with the corresponding client name so the joins are working. Although, only the client.name and addresses.address ever consistently appear. I need the address_id in the button to be able to book for that address, unfortunately, when the done=0 address_id is blank.

[image: This is the data that appears]

Is there any way that I can get the same result from the joins, while also getting the address_id?

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`. Always name and qualify only those columns that you want returned

Comment: Whats wrong with SELECT *? @Strawberry

Comment: This is something of a FAQ

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the joins the other way.  Then you should list the columns that you are using explicitly:

```
select c.name, a.address, a.address_id, coalesce(b.done, 1) as completed
from clients c left join
     bookings b
     on b.client_id = c.client_id and b.done = 0 left join
     addresses a
     on b.address_id = a.address_id ;
```

Also note that I changed the table aliases so they are abbreviations for the table name -- much easier to follow than confusing aliases.

Comment: The bookings table does not include the client_id and only includes address_id so I linked the bookings.address_id to addresses.address_id and addresses.client_id to clients.client_id

Comment: each booking is per address_id not the client_id

Comment: Since a client might have two addresses if I use and search bookings by client_id, it won't show each address.

Comment: @Jackbeeby . . . This will show all addresses for a client, if you filter for a particular client.